# The spaces between these lines differs between browsers, and line-height doesn't seem to fix it

Tags: html, cross-browser, css

My heading ('header') and subheading ('subh') are displayed with different vertical spacing in different browsers.  In Firefox it displays the way I want it to, but in Safari and Chrome, there's a massive gap.![Safari and Chrome example][1]

I've tried the line-height property, and it doesn't fix anything, and I've tried it with percentages, fractions and negatives (I have no idea if negatives do anything).

This is my CSS. I apologise if it's not stylistically correct, as I only started with HTML last month. Apparently my image won't show up either, so I hope I described it adequately.

`header {
            background-color: white;
            float: left;
            font-family: "Arvo";
            font-size: 300%;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        subh {
            background-color: white;
            color: #33CC33;
            float: left;
            font-family: "Josefin Slab";
            font-size:200%;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
            position: relative;
            top: 7.5%;
            width: 100%;
        }`

Answer (score 1):

I think different browsers may be handling your typo:

font-size: 300%%;

Differently.  Remove the extra %.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've just come back having realised that I added that in now. Unfortunately it wasn't the cause.

Comment: Okay, another thing that sticks out is that this CSS is looking for elements header and subh, which to me seems like a mistake.  Should they be classes instead?  In this case, check your markup and prefix your css names with a period.  For example:  .header {...}

Post your HTML and that will help us solve the problem faster.

Comment: I have since realised what was going wrong, and it was silly. See answer below. Thank you very much. I will still take your advice and go add the periods now.I'm still coming to grips with classes and divs, so at times I probably misuse them, and I think it'll improve with research and application.

Comment: Periods indicate Class Selectors, so that will only work if your elements have classes, something like this: `<div class="subh">`, but glad you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised what was wrong, and I'm somewhat ashamed. The combination of having position set to 'relative' and having the differing 'top' values caused the gaps. I still don't know why that displayed differently in different browsers, but it seems to be the case. I think I initially had them set to 'fixed'.

I have since set the top value for my heading and subheading to 0.